# Headphones in USB-C Hub are recognized as an external monitor

Tags: 20.04, headphones

I bought a Falwedi USB-C hub ([this one](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07M8QR83T/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)), but when I plug my headset into the hub's 3.5mm jack, my machine thinks it is an external monitor:

[image]

How can I fix this or at least, how can I diagnose if this is the USB-C hub's fault or Ubuntu's fault?

(*I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with Unity*)

Comment: What is the problem ? Doesn't they play ? Probably it is the USB hub that present it's 3.5 mm jack as external monitor - which a headphone set technically also are.

Comment: It's not true that a headphone set is technically an external monitor, they're 2 different things.  Also, the headphone set is being recognized as an external monitor that has no speakers, so after plugging in, I have no additional audio options.

Comment: same problem here, still no good answer?

Answer (score 1):

Ughh, ok it seems to be the USB-C hub.  Reading through Amazon, sounds like people (on different operating systems) get all kinds of crazy behavior with the audio jack, some similar to mine, ex: "when I connect to the audio output my screen changes its settings as if I were using HDMI".