# Hub multi-port mistook for an external monitor when headphones plaggued in

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, headphones

I bought [this hub](https://www.amazon.fr/Adaptateur-Multiport-10-en-1-Ethernet-Tablette/dp/B0836MZXP9/ref=mp_s_a_1_9?crid=2N1KD9LGCUQCP&keywords=adaptateur%20multiport%20usb&qid=1665243369&qu=eyJxc2MiOiI0LjQ5IiwicXNhIjoiMy43MiIsInFzcCI6IjMuMjEifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=adaptateur%20multiport%20usb%2Caps%2C105&sr=8-9), and, whenever I plague my headphones in, the computer thinks I got an external monitor (see attached screenshot).

I tried with different headphones and the result is the same. I have a DELL XPS 13 PLUS, and Ubuntu 22 on it.

I also found [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358252/headphones-in-usb-c-hub-are-recognized-as-an-external-monitor) but no solution was provided.

Thanks!

[image: Two monitors]

Comment: No solution was provided in the other Q&A you linked because there isn't one: https://askubuntu.com/a/1358263/1210606 It's an hardware quirkiness unrelated to the OS.

Comment: @ChanganAuto in fact, the answer is provided in that other question: the issue is with the hub, not Ubuntu.

Comment: how do I know that my problem is in th ehub?

Comment: @zwets Exactly, that's what I said while agreeing with no actual solution being provided, other the implicit get another device.

Comment: @FdA How do you know? Occam's razor - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor - when you have multiple customers on multiple OSes reporting this same issue in a very similar device it stands to reason the problem is the same. The negative reviews in yours mostly complain about the audio output not working or HDMI/VGA not working but the latter is probably from users who don't know their USB-C has no alternate mode.

Comment: Anyway this isn't really a problem, just a very minor annoyance. Just select "single display" and make sure you select the actual one. Be happy.

Comment: @karel if you look at my question, I already pointed out the same website. It actually doesn't answer as the hub is different and I don't see any similar comments on Amazon. As was saying, it might be the case due to Occam's razor, even if we didn't explore many other options.

Comment: @FdA OK, retracted.